# Disable phone number synchronisation across multiple phones

Tags: iphone, icloud

In thehousehold i live in we use multiple phones on the same account.

Now the problem is, that when one device texts/writes an email it uses a different phones number/email /account information.

Is there a way to disable this, appart from using different apple accounts.

Comment: Does it use the phone number/email address from the Apple ID account holder?

Comment: no, it uses mine ( i am not the account holder)

Comment: All of them use your info, regardless of the account holder or who sent an email/text last?